# Issue with rendering a component as a prop

Tags: reactjs, react-props, react-component

I have a layout component which acts as follows:

```
const Layout = ({ children, sider }) => (
  <div>
    <div>{sider}</div>
    {children}
  </div>
)
```

But I can't implement it as expected. I'm hoping to get it implemented as follows:

```
<Layout sider={Sider}>
  Body Content Here
</Layout>
```

Where `Sider` is another React component.

However when I do this, my `Sider` component doesn't render.

I can only get it to work like this:

```
<Layout sider={<Sider />}>
  Body Content Here
</Layout>
```

How can I update my `Layout` component so that I can implement `sider={Sider}` instead of `sider={<Sider />}`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your 2nd approach is correct however if you still want to do that way, do like this

```js
const Layout = ({ children, sider: Sider }) => (
  <div>
    <div>
      <Sider />
    </div>
    {children}
  </div>
)
```

Comment: I know this is a counter productive question, but in the odd case that I want to add a component with props in there, would it be possible to do something like `sider={() => <Component name="hello" />}`?

Comment: `sider={() => <Component name="hello" />}` is same as your original question.

Answer (score 0):

Another method to handle this is to use [React.createElement()](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-api.html#createelement)

Example:

```
const Layout = ({ children, sider }) => (
  <div>
    <div>{React.createElement(sider)}</div>
    {children}
  </div>
)
```